# .NET 2 DataTables in one single DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, dataset

I got a Dataset that fills a gridview. The gridview has to be filled with one dataset and multiple queries (or datatables in this instance).

As you can see in the code I used 2 DataTables. These Datatables are filled from a database (with sql server). The Datatables are added to one Dataset. In the ASP code you can see there are 3 labels and also 3 columns in the gridview. The first 2 columns are from the first datatable or the first query. The second query fills the last or third column.

When I run this code it doesn't find `lblThree` in the dataset. `LblThree` is in the dataset but in the second table and .NET doesn't know that I guess. Do you guys know a solution for this error so I can fill my gridview with one dataset?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TwoDatatableToDataset
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                loadAll();
            }
        }

        private void loadAll()
        {   // STEP ONE Put one sql output in an empty dataset: (works well)
            //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            //string sql = "select SID1 as lblOne, Charge_Amount as lblTwo from [xxx].[xxxx].[xxxx]";
            //SqlConnection Scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testserver"].ConnectionString);
            //SqlCommand Scmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Scon);
            //Scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(Scmd); // all data in adapter
            //Scon.Open();
            //adp.Fill(ds); //Adapter in dataset
            //GridView1.DataSource = ds; //dataset in gridview
            //GridView1.DataBind();

            //STEP TWO Make 2 datatables set them in one dataset
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            string sql = "select SID1 as lblOne, Charge_Amount as lblTwo from [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx]";            
            SqlConnection Scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testserver"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand Scmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Scon);
            Scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(Scmd); // all data in adapter
            Scon.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt); //Adapter in dataset

            sql = "select Currency as lblThree from [xxx].[dbo].[tbl_xx_NI]";            
            Scmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Scon);
            Scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(Scmd); // all data in adapter
            adp.Fill(dt2); //Adapter in dataset

            ds.Tables.Add(dt); //add data table to data set
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds; //dataset in gridview
            GridView1.DataBind(); // ERROR: A field or property with the name 'lblThree' was not found on the selected data source.

            Scon.Close();
        }
    }
}





    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TwoDatatableToDataset._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False">
                     <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lblOne" HeaderText="One" SortExpression="lblOne">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%"/>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lblTwo" HeaderText="Two" SortExpression="lblTwo">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lblThree" HeaderText="Three" SortExpression="lblThree">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>   
                     </Columns>       
                </asp:GridView>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution really depends on what you're trying to do. There are probably two main options that you'll want to look into though:

1. Query the `DataSet` programmatically, and merge the results using LINQ
2. Use a nested `GridView` or `ListView` to generate the expected output

Personally, I would opt for the LINQ option, but that's up to you. The article below should help to get you pointed in the right direction.

http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2009/02/11/129310.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you could call `Merge`.

```
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

It seems as though this is the table you essentially want to bind. Anyway, try this and breakpoint the merge method. Step over and see what `dt1` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use UNION in your sql command like this :

select SID1 as lblOne, Charge_Amount as lblTwo from [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx]
UNION
select Currency as lblThree from [xxxx].[dbo].[tbl_xx_NI]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, couldn't you create a view in your database, using the filters that you would use in your queries so that it would represent a dataset that would contain all the information that you need, so that you could query the view and store the results in a single data table?